# Issue in apex programming

Tags: apex

Below is the problem statement which has been given for the assignment.

Problem Statement: Fire a query on account where Industry=Chemical & collect all those records id in set.Final output should be set.

Below is the code which I have written

```
public class SetIndustryChemical {

    public Mylist(String list, Integer Id)
    {
        List<Account> Acclist = New list<Account>();
        AccList.add(Name = 'Rumi Bajaj', Industry = 'Chemical');
        AccList.add(Name = 'Gautam Bajaj', Industry = 'Chemical');
        AccList.add(Name = 'Parth', Industry = 'Chemical');
        system.debug('Current List='+AccList);   
        Acclist = [SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Industry='Chemical'];
        Set<id> AccSet = New Set<id>();
        for (Account a : Acclist){
            AccSet.add(a.id);
        }
    }
}
```

[![Here is the snip of error that I am getting. I have also attached the snip. Can you help me fix this code.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBcv5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBcv5.png)

Comment: Your method is missing a return value - add void.  Try `public void Mylist(String list, Integer Id)`

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, your method signature is incorrect i.e. it doesn't have the return type.

If you don't want to return anything from your method, you should mention `void` as your return type in your method. If you want to call this method from visualforce page, then return type should be `PageReference`. If you want to return the `set` which is created in the method, then your return type should be `set<Id>`

**Summary**

- Don't want to return anything --> Return type of method should be `void`
- Want to use it from commandButton from Visualforce Page --> Return type of method should be `PageReference`
- Want to return the set which is created in method --> Return type of method should be `Set<Id>`

Also, there is no need to pass the parameters to your method, as you are using none. And not sure why you are adding elements to the `list` which is getting over written by the results of the `SOQL` statements

Your class should look like this

```
public class SetIndustryChemical {

    public void Mylist() {
        //inserting 3 records with Industy as Chemical
        List<Account> Acclist = New list<Account>();
        AccList.add(new Account ( Name = 'Rumi Bajaj', Industry = 'Chemical'));
        AccList.add(new Account ( Name = 'Gautam Bajaj', Industry = 'Chemical'));
        AccList.add(new Account ( Name = 'Parth', Industry = 'Chemical'));
        insert AccList;

        Set<id> AccSet = New Set<id>();
        for (Account a:[SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Industry='Chemical']){
            AccSet.add(a.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AccList.add(Name = 'Rumi Bajaj', Industry = 'Chemical'); // Error Variable Name and Industry does not exist

Comment: Why are you adding values to the list ? Are you trying to create new records, if yes, then you will have to insert that list as well. There was a syntax error as well in your code. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

I see below issues with your code:
1)You are missing return type of the method. I have put void as the return type.
2) You have added extra closing braces ('}'). I have removed it from the last line.

Try below code:

```
public class SetIndustryChemical {

public void Mylist(String list, Integer Id)
{
    List<Account> Acclist = New list<Account>();
    AccList.add(Name = 'Rumi Bajaj', Industry = 'Chemical');
    AccList.add(Name = 'Gautam Bajaj', Industry = 'Chemical');
    AccList.add(Name = 'Parth', Industry = 'Chemical');
    system.debug('Current List='+AccList);   
    Acclist=[SELECT id FROM Account WHERE Industry='Chemical'];
    Set<Account> AccSet = New Set<Account>();
    For(Account a : AccList)
    {
       AccSet.add(a.Id);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: still not working.. giving errors.. please assist me.. \n  AccSet.add(a.Id);    // Error variable Id does not exist \n AccList.add(Name = 'Rumi Bajaj', Industry = 'Chemical'); // Error Variable Name and Industry does not exist

Comment: This is because you haven't inserted the account yet. Add a line - Insert Acclist; , before system.debug() statement